# CMD Lazy evaluation (String Replace) + Multiple Commands in a single line with "&"

Tags: replace, cmd

I want to convert a local path to a UNC path in a single command line.

To do this, I'm hoping to replace `C:` in my local path with `\\%ComputerName%\c$`, and then call my network resource with `"\\Server\Resources\FileReceiver.exe" "%output%"`, passing my `%output%` as a command line argument.

I have a working ProofOfConcept.cmd file which looks like this:

```
SET "output=C:\MyFile.txt"
CALL SET output=%%output:C:=\\%ComputerName%\c$%%
"\\Server\Resources\FileReceiver.exe" "%output%"
pause
```

and outputs:

```
C:\>SET "output=C:\MyFile.txt"
C:\>CALL SET output=%output:C:=\\%ComputerName%\c$%
C:\>"\\Server\Resources\FileReceiver.exe" "\\PC-01\c$\MyFile.txt"
FileReceiver Util v1.0.3.94365

accepting \\PC-01\c$\MyFile.txt...

FileReceiver.exe exited on Server exited with error code 0.
C:\>pause
Press any key to continue . . .
```

So this works, but for my particular use-case, I need to concatenate the commands onto a single executable line, so I replace newlines with `&` and my ProofOfConcept.cmd now looks like this:

```
SET "output=C:\MyFile.txt" & CALL SET output=%%output:C:=\\%ComputerName%\c$%% & "\\Server\Resources\FileReceiver.exe" "%output%"
```

But instead of a formatted path, %output% is now an empty string (""):

```
C:\>SET "output=C:\MyFile.txt"   & CALL SET output=%output:C:=\\%ComputerName%\c$%   & "\\Server\Resources\FileReceiver.exe" ""   & pause
Press any key to continue . .
```

What am I doing wrong? If I add a second line to my .cmd file `echo %output%` I get a value, but it's not evaluating on the first line. I'm guessing something about lazy evaluation + threading, but I'm not sure how to resolve. Do I need to string replace my entire execution line FIRST, and then CALL it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right about the lazy evaluation. You could put the last command in another CALL:

```
SET "output=C:\MyFile.txt" & CALL SET output=%%output:C:=\\%ComputerName%\c$%% & CALL "\\Server\Resources\FileReceiver.exe" "%%output%%"
```

This works for me.

EDIT: Note the double percents in the last CALL ("%%output%%") . This is important because the percents must be 'escaped' to be passed into the CALL context as "%output%". Good call pointing this out, @epicTurkey. Thanks!

Comment: THANK YOU! Along with CALL'ing the command, your code shows that you replaced %output% with %%output%%. This is required for the lazy parser, and may be a helpful detail to point out in your answer for others.